# C++ / OOP: Class with implicit dependency on other class

Tags: c++, oop

I'm writing a program in OpenGL. There is a `Gfx` class which holds an OpenGL context and wraps the OpenGL library.
There is also a `Texture` class which wraps OpenGL texture names (including generation and deletion). The `Texture` class naturally has an implicit dependency on the `Gfx` class. But I want RAII, no pointers, and therefore think that the `Texture` class must be publicly accessible.

What is the cleanest way to express the dependency on a constructed `Gfx` instance?

Comment: How would you handle a context loss? I.e. in OpenGL ES 2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the texture cannot exist without the context, looks like the constructor argument is proper in this case, possibly a `std::shared_ptr<Gfx>` (hope this is excused from your no-pointer policy - I consider it a C++ construct). This way Gfx will linger as long as at least one Texture is not disposed.

Comment: I think storing a reference is too much (runtime) overhead! I'm more hoping for static assertions.